# What kind of problem is the membership problem of a recursive enumerable language?

Tags: computer-science, computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

Is it correct that the membership problem (i.e. the characteristic function) of a recursive language is a decidable i.e. computable problem?

What kind of problem is the membership problem of a recursive enumerable language, as opposed to the membership problem of a non r.e. language? Is the membership problem of a recursive enumerable language also decidable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By membership problem, you mean if a word is an element of the recursive language? Then yes, by definition: A language is recursive, if there is a turing machine (TM) that halts and accepts words which are elements of the language.
The difference between recursive and recursive enumerable language is that a TM for a recursive language always halts but a TM for recursive enumerable language is not guaranteed to hold for words not in the language (it might loop forever). We call the latter therefor [semidecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)#Semidecidability)